# How to generate shorter logs with Webpack and Angular2?

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm using angular 2 starter project and I have a looooooot of logs. 
Typically if I have an error, I have 100 lines of logs related to polyfills.bundle and main.bundle and I need to scroll all the way up to see the 'real' error.